# Integrating an interpolating function

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, interpolation, finite-element-method

I have been using the following `NDEigensystem` command to generate the eigenfunctions of the laplacian with a square domain:

```
 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]

{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[
    {-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
    u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ , 4];
```

However, I am trying to compute the following integral over $D$, where `funs[[3]]` is the third eigenfunction given by `NDEigensystem`:

$\qquad \int_{}\mbox{funs[[3]]}\cdot \mbox{funs[[3]]}$

My guess was:

```
NIntegrate[Dot[funs[[3]], funs[[3]]], {x, y} ∈ ]
```

but this doesn't return a numerical value for me. I would be grateful if somebody could give me a working code for the integral.

Comment: I believe that the `funs[[3]]` is a scalar value and thus `Dot` is not the correct call. You may just be looking to multiply  `funs[[3]]*funs[[3]]` inside the argument of `NIntegrate`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! this is Interesting; it returns the value 1 which sounds good to me. However, it does give me the following error:

"the global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more \
than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease \
monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of \
the following: the working precision is insufficient for the \
specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it \
is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the \
integral is 0.

Comment: Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option \
MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. \
NIntegrate obtained 1. and 1.16566*10^-6 for the integral and error \
estimates."

Comment: Yeah, I see these sort of warnings a lot. Someone more skilled with the inner workings of `NIntegrate` could probably give you some options to set. I tend to prefer, for simple functions like this, using my own numerical integration scheme. See my post here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41212/nintegrateslwcon-problem/41216#41216

Comment: @MrS100 Is an error of around `10^-6` acceptable?  If so, you can use the result.

Comment: Try to integrate over the ElementMesh from the InterpolatingFunction and see if that helps.

Comment: Good Idea - this certainly doesn't show an error message anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Updated after reading @user21's comment. My original approach was equivalent, but this is more direct.]

Since `NDEigensystem` returns an interpolation over an `ElementMesh`, it seems appropriate to integrate over it.

```
reg = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}];
{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u, {x, y} ∈ reg, 4];

NIntegrate[funs[[3]][x, y]^2, {x, y} ∈ funs[[3]]["ElementMesh"]]
(*  1.  *)

% - 1
(*  -4.44089*10^-16  *)
```

Comment: This is excellent. It seems to give exactly what I want and uses terminology of which I am familiar with. For that reason, I shall mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem, at least in part, comes from integrating over a region. Since this region is a simple square, you could substitute

```
NIntegrate[funs[[3]]^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

This evaluates quickly and returns

> `0.999998`

On the other hand,

```
NIntegrate[funs[[3]]^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Method -> "MultiPeriodic"]
```

takes longer to evaluate but returns

> `1.`

which be a more accurate value.

Comment: Thanks for your response m_goldberg. This works well! Upvoted!