# Optimizing NIntegrate to compute marginal distributions specified by interpolating functions

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration, interpolation

It has already been pointed out in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119483/how-to-speed-up-nintegrate-when-using-an-interpolating-function-output-from-ndei) that using the element mesh of the interpolating function greatly reduces the time it takes to compute numerical integrals over the whole domain of the function.

Can a similar optimization be used to compute and plot the marginal distributions? For example, let $\psi(x_1,x_2)$ be some computed eigenfunction, and interpret $\lvert \psi(x_1,x_2) \rvert^2$ as a probability distribution, then how can we quickly find
$$ M_1(x_1) = \int \lvert \psi(x_1,x_2) \rvert^2 \ dx_2$$
$$ M_2(x_2) = \int \lvert \psi(x_1,x_2) \rvert^2 \ dx_1?$$

For the case of two quantum mechanical particles in a 1D infinite well, with an inter-particle interaction $V_{int} \sim \alpha (x_1-x_2)^2$ we can use NDEigensystem to find the lowest 3 eigenfunctions numerically.

```
\[Alpha] = -(1/10000);
{Evals, Efuncts} = 
NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[\[Psi][x1, x2], {x1, x2}] + (\[Alpha] (x1 - x2)^2) \[Psi][x1, x2], 
DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x1, x2] == 0, True]}, \[Psi], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, 3];
```

Then plot the single particle probability distributions for the particle $x_2$, what I have just called $M_2(x_2)$ above

```
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[Plot[Quiet[
NIntegrate[Efuncts[[i]][x1, x2] Efuncts[[i]][x1, x2], {x1, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 100]], 
{x2, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, Length[Efuncts]}]]
```

[image]

Although solving the system is very fast, plotting the single particle probability distributions takes almost a minute (sometimes significantly longer, depending on the value of $\alpha$). In contrast, doing almost any integral over the entire domain of interest using the aforementioned optimization takes less than a second.

```
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[NIntegrate[
Exp[-x1^2 - x2^2]*Efuncts[[i]][x1, x2] Efuncts[[i]][x1, x2], {x1, x2} \[Element] 
Efuncts[[1]]["ElementMesh"]], {i, 1, 3}]]

{0.732146, {0.587017, 0.564539, 0.587082}}
```

Comment: In order to potentially receive help, you should at least provide copy-able code for the $\psi$ and the integral(s).

Comment: @Lukas Sorry, I'm not sure why that's helpful. I could pick some NDEigensystem to solve and Plot/NIntegrate code, but that's just one random example. The question is a general one about characteristics all such problems share.

Answer (score 1):

For plotting you don't need high precision and accuracy. So, decreasing those speeds up plotting. Also, you can switch off symbolic processing. Code demonstrating this follows.

```
\[Alpha] = -(1/10000);
{Evals, Efuncts} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[\[Psi][x1, x2], {x1, 
        x2}] + (\[Alpha] (x1 - x2)^2) \[Psi][x1, x2], 
    DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x1, x2] == 0, True]}, \[Psi], {x1, 0, 
    1}, {x2, 0, 1}, 3];

AbsoluteTiming[
 Table[Plot[
   NIntegrate[Efuncts[[i]][x1, x2] Efuncts[[i]][x1, x2], {x1, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3, MaxRecursion -> 10], {x2, 
    0, 1}, PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, Length[Efuncts]}]]
```

[image]