# Is there a way to let NDEigensystem output discrete eigenfunctions rather than InterpolatingFunctions?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, finite-element-method

I am new to Mathematica and I encountered a speed problem.

I want to do tons of integrations of multiplications of two eigenfunctions (or matrix elements in physical terms). The speed now is quite unsatisfying.

As I only require numerical results, I would like to know how to speed up this process. The most efficient way I could think of is to get the discretized eigenfunctions. But I would also like to know how and at which stage discretization of the eigenfunctions could speed up the whole calculation **most**.

For example, the problem is

```
{eige, eigv}=NDEigensystem[SomeSystem];
result[[i,j]]=NIntegrate[eigv[[i]] eigv[[j]]];
```

Here `i` and `j` are different solutions corresponding to `eige[[i]]` and `eige[[j]]` respectively.

The stages I could think of are:

1. When solving the differential eigensystem using `NDEigensystem`, (get discretized `eigv` at `NDEigensystem`)
2. When solved, transform the eigenfunction of the form `InterpolatingFunction` into discrete ones, (discretize the `eigv` which is now in `InterpolatingFunction` before `NIntegration` and then integrate by dot product.)
3. When using `NIntegration`.

And, I would be very thankful if you could also teach me how to do it in these ways.

A specific example is below:

```
num = 10;
AbsoluteTiming[{eige, eigv} = NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], u[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, num];]
AbsoluteTiming[Sum[NIntegrate[eigv[[i]] x eigv[[j]], {x, 0, \[Pi]}], {i, 1,num}, {j, 1, num}]]
```

When `num` is as large as 100, the result is super slow.

**Editted**

After some efforts trying to understand the stages taken by `NDEigensystem`, I give up letting the function itself output discretized data. *Although it seems this function contains a normalization process (or stage) after interpolation stage*, I do not think I could realize arbitrary integration as fast as the internal function do. I found we can discretize the solution by hand. See below

```
Clear[x, u];
num = 40;
delta = 0.01;
{eige, eigv} = NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], u[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, num];
Sum[NIntegrate[eigv[[i]] x eigv[[j]], {x} \[Element] (eigv[[1]] /. x -> "ElementMesh")], {i, 1, num}, {j, 1, num}] // Timing
Sum[NIntegrate[eigv[[i]] x eigv[[j]], {x, 0, \[Pi]}], {i, 1, num}, {j, 1, num}] // Timing
AbsoluteTiming[
xRange = Range[0, \[Pi], delta];
eigvv = Table[eigv, {x, xRange}];
Print[Dimensions[eigvv], Dimensions[xRange]];
Sum[eigvv[[All, i]].(eigvv[[All, j]] xRange) delta, {i, 1, num}, {j, 1, num}]]
(*
{30.5625, 61.5422}
some warnings
{41.1875, 61.5243}
{315,40}{315}
{0.158992, 61.8818}
*)
```

The improvement is almost two orders.

Comment: Can you post a working, minimal example of what you want?

Comment: Hi, I have added a specific example. The resulted eigenfunction is rather smooth, so I think this code should have a better performance even though the integration is performed many times.

Comment: Do you want that `x` in the `NIntegrate` of your specific example?

Comment: Yeah, I hope there is a general solution for this. That `x` is an example, and you can even generalize to any function `f[x]` to insert between eigenfunctions and also the eigenfunction could be a vector itself.

Comment: I tried the solution from another  [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119483/how-to-speed-up-nintegrate-when-using-an-interpolating-function-output-from-ndei?rq=1) but it is weird that it is not actually calculating. `Sum[NIntegrate[eigv[[i]] x eigv[[j]], 
  x \[Element] eigv[[2]]["ElementMesh"]], {i, 1, num}, {j, 1, num}]`. Besides, it seems  that from the `FullForm`, eigenfunctions are already discretized.

Answer (score 7):

You can extract the values from the grid:

```
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], u, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 10];
funs[[3]]["ValuesOnGrid"]
```

Extract the mesh with:

```
funs[[3]]["ElementMesh"]
```

If you want to stay with your original formulation `u[x]` than you can use:

```
Head[funs[[3]][x]]["ValuesOnGird"]
```

Or another alternative:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Line[{{0}, {Pi}}]];
num = 10;
{vals, eigv} = 
  NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], u, Element[{x}, mesh], num];
funs[[3]]["ValuesOnGrid"]
AbsoluteTiming[
 Sum[NIntegrate[eigv[[i]][x] x eigv[[j]][x], Element[{x}, mesh]], {i, 
   1, num}, {j, 1, num}]]
{1.091801`, 19.03787410869329`}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I also need grid information to perform an integration. How to extract that?

Comment: @XiaoyuLiu, see update (and Documentation for [ElementMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMesh.html))

Comment: By the way in my example, I used `u[x]` instead of `u` as the second argument of `NDEigensystem` and in that way I cannot extract "ValuesOnGrid" and "ElementMesh". The result is always in the form of interpolating function. Can you explain me why is that?

Comment: I tested a little bit on this difference and found they are not the same. When using u[x] it is pretty much like a function. The most important difference is when you want to extract discrete points. Try the following:`{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], u, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 10];
{eige, eigv} = 
  NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], u[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, num];
vec1 = Table[eigv[[3]], {x, 0, \[Pi], 0.01}]
vec2 = Table[funs[[3]], {x, 0, \[Pi], 0.01}]`. Now the question is what is the correct way to extract `ValuesOnGrid` from my original definition with `u[x]`?

Comment: @XiaoyuLiu, you can use `Head[u[x]]["ValuesOnGird"]`.

Comment: Sorry, when and where should I use that? Out of `NDEigensystem` mathematica doesn't know the definition of `u[x]` any more.

Comment: @XiaoyuLiu, see update.

Comment: This is good, but where is `"ElementMesh"`? I think I need at least step size or the length of the segments.  And by the way I tested on discrete dot product, it is at least two orders faster. However, the interpolating process I used to extract the discrete numbers are slow (Using `Table`). If I could get discretized eigenfunctions directly, that would be the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

In response to a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165427/is-there-a-way-to-let-ndeigensystem-output-discrete-eigenfunctions-rather-than-i#comment437501_165449):

> Thank you, but I also need grid information to perform an integration....

There are built-in methods for integrating over an `ElementMesh`, which are automatically invoked if you use the `ElementMesh` as the integration domain:

```
Clear[x, u];
num = 40;
AbsoluteTiming[{eige, eigv} = NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], u[x], {x, 0, π}, num];]
AbsoluteTiming[
 Sum[
  NIntegrate[eigv[[i]] x eigv[[j]], {x} ∈ (eigv[[1]] /. x -> "ElementMesh")],
  {i, 1, num}, {j, 1, num}]]
(*
  {0.019178, Null}
  {21.7475, 61.5422}
*)
```

Compare with approach in the OP:

```
AbsoluteTiming[{eige, eigv} = NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], u[x], {x, 0, π}, num];]
AbsoluteTiming[
 Sum[NIntegrate[eigv[[i]] x eigv[[j]], {x, 0, π}],
  {i, 1, num}, {j, 1, num}]]
(*
  {0.018287, Null}

  ...NIntegrate warnings...

  {35.0064, 61.5243}
*)
```