# How to write a function of a polynomial

Tags: functions, function-construction, polynomials

I will illustrate my problem with this example:

I want to make a function which, given a polynomial, gives me the value of the integral $\int_0^1(ax+bx^2)dx=a/2+b/3$.

Therefore, in this example, I want something like

```
fun[Poly(x)]:=Coefficient[Poly(x),x,1]/2+Coefficient[Poly(x),x,2]/3;
```

Do you know how can I define the argument of this function? Because it is a function of $x$ but I want to write the full polynomial of $x$ in the argument.

Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is always the argument:

```
fun[poly_ /; PolynomialQ[poly, x]] := Expand[poly] /. x^n_. -> 1/(n+1)
fun[a x + b x^2]
```

> a/2 + b/3

If you want to be able to specify the argument:

```
fun[poly_, arg_] /; PolynomialQ[poly, arg] := Expand[poly] /. arg^n_. -> 1/(n+1)
fun[a x + b x^2, x]
```

> a/2 + b/3

The dot in the pattern `x^n_.` is a [`Default` pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) that matches both `x^n` and `x` (defaulting to `n=1` in the latter).

Answer (score 2):

One can of course write this in terms of `Integrate[]`, but I had presented an alternative routine, `polyInt[]`, in [this previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184119), based on an algorithm due to Kahan. Applied to your example, we have

```
polyInt[a x + b x^2, {x, 0, 1}]
   a/2 + b/3
```