# Problem with Integration

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to integrate a function which seems to have no regularity problems. In fact I have defined

```
K[x_, y_] := 
 Assuming[Element[{x, y}, Reals] && x > 0 && y > 0, 
 NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 - (Cos[x]*Cos[y] + Sin[x]*Sin[y]*Cos[t])^2], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]]
R[x_, 0] := (x - Pi/2)^2
H[x_, 0] := 
 Assuming[Element[{x}, Reals] && x > 0, NIntegrate[Sin[t]*K[x, t]*R[t, 0], {t, 0, Pi}]]
```

If I plot, the function I obtain a good output

```
Sin[x]*Exp[-10*H[x, 0]
```

[image]

But if I try to integrate it, even with NIntegrate I receive the following error messages

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Sqrt[1-(Cos[t] Cos[x]+Cos[t] Sin[t] Sin[x])^2] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,6.28319}}.
General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::inumr will be suppressed during this calculation.
NIntegrate::write: Tag Times in -Abs[t] is Protected.
General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::write will be suppressed during this calculation.
NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.0217285}. NIntegrate obtained 2.897189900542515`*^-18 and 3.722470516152078`*^-24 for the integral and error estimates.
```

why is that?

Comment: `But if I try to integrate it` you did not show the code for this.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that 
NIntegrate[Sin[x]*Exp[-10*H[x, 0]], {x, 0, Pi}]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The main difficulty here is the tiny value of your function and, by consequence, of its integral. Left to its own devices, it is difficult for `NIntegrate` to decide when it has done a "good enough" job of estimating an integral if its actual value is (close to) zero, since the default `PrecisionGoal` can never be satisfied (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41297/27951)). In those cases, you should **impose a finite** `AccuracyGoal` **instead**.
- I have also removed the assumptions because `NIntegrate` won't need them; you already take care that they are satisfied when you chose the integration range yourself.
- In passing, avoid using single-letter uppercase symbols, as most of those have built-in meanings and you could get into conflicts; I have changed those to lower case below.

Here is the modified code:

```
ClearAll[k, r, h, K, R, H]

k[x_, y_] :=  NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 - (Cos[x]*Cos[y] + Sin[x]*Sin[y]*Cos[t])^2], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
r[x_, 0] = (x - Pi/2)^2;
h[x_?NumericQ, 0] := NIntegrate[Sin[t]*k[x, t]*r[t, 0], {t, 0, Pi}]

NIntegrate[
  Sin[x]*Exp[-10*h[x, 0]], {x, 0, Pi},
  AccuracyGoal -> 5
]

(* Out: 2.8684*10^-18 *)
```

The calculation is pretty quick ([`RepeatedTiming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html) returns 0.130 s).

---

The plot of your function was also a little rough; you can use more plot points to improve its quality. Below is the function plotted together with its integral on a range from 0 to $x$:

```
Show[
  Plot[Sin[x]*Exp[-10*h[x, 0]], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 200],

  Plot[
    NIntegrate[
      Sin[x]*Exp[-10*h[x, 0]], {x, 0, limit},
      AccuracyGoal -> 5
    ],
    {limit, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All,
    PlotPoints -> 40, MaxRecursion -> 1,
    PlotStyle -> Red
  ]
]
```

[image: function and its integral]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
K[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 Assuming[Element[{x, y}, Reals] && x > 0 && y > 0, 
  NIntegrate[
   Sqrt[1 - (Cos[x]*Cos[y] + Sin[x]*Sin[y]*Cos[t])^2], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]]
R[x_?NumericQ, 0] := (x - Pi/2)^2
H[x_?NumericQ, 0] := 
 Assuming[Element[{x}, Reals] && x > 0, 
  NIntegrate[Sin[t]*K[x, t]*R[t, 0], {t, 0, Pi}]]
```

And only now do

```
NIntegrate[Sin[x]*Exp[-10*H[x, 0]], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

It is still running, but at least no error now. The above insures the function are called only with numerical arguments.

It finished after about 5 minutes:

[image]